# Add module nginx psql

Tags: postgresql, nginx

I need to add the `http_postgres_module` module

Here's what I do:

```
root @ fp-desk: /home/floriane/openresty-1.11.2.5# ./configure --with-http_postgres_module;
```

It compiles some but not completely. I get this error:

> - ngx_http_form_input_module was configured
>     adding module in ../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.06
>     found ngx_devel_kit for ngx_encrypted_session; looks good.
> - ngx_http_encrypted_session_module was configured
>     adding module in ../ngx_postgres-1.0
>
> checking for libpq library version 9.1 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 9.0 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.4 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.3 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.2 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.1.4 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.1.0 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.0.8 ... not found
>   checking for libpq library version 8.0.0 ... not found
>
> ./configure: error: ngx_postgres addon was unable to detect version of the libpq library.
>
> ERROR: failed to run command: sh ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx ...
>
> root@fp-desk:/home/floriane/openresty-1.11.2.5#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CentOS or RHEL user, try to install `postgresql-devel` package.

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

This works for me.